# How do I find errors in an Angular 6 template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I've created an ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application with an Angular 6 front-end. When it works, it works, but when I make an error in some template code, for instance creating an empty span in app.component:

```
<span />
```

Everything will compile and Angular will run, but it will remain stuck on the basic "loading" page defined in index.html. There's no error anywhere in the browser's developer tools, and none in Visual Studio's various output windows. As soon as I fix the offending tag:

```
<span></span>
```

and save the document, the page reloads and everything works.

Where are errors like these reported so that I can find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the `ng build --prod` command this will give you a more exact location of where  errors are.